# Quering date from date and time field

Tags: mysql, php

I have a table which is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `candidate` (
  `candidate_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `middle_name` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_home` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_cell` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_work` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `city` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_available` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `can_relocate` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `key_skills` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `current_employer` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `entered_by` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Created-by user.',
  `owner` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_created` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `date_modified` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email1` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email2` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `web_site` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `import_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_hot` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `eeo_ethnic_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `eeo_veteran_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `eeo_disability_status` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `eeo_gender` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  `desired_pay` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_pay` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_active` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `is_admin_hidden` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `best_time_to_call` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And some of the data is like this.

```
INSERT INTO `candidate` (`candidate_id`, `site_id`, `last_name`, `first_name`, `middle_name`, `phone_home`, `phone_cell`, `phone_work`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `source`, `date_available`, `can_relocate`, `notes`, `key_skills`, `current_employer`, `entered_by`, `owner`, `date_created`, `date_modified`, `email1`, `email2`, `web_site`, `import_id`, `is_hot`, `eeo_ethnic_type_id`, `eeo_veteran_type_id`, `eeo_disability_status`, `eeo_gender`, `desired_pay`, `current_pay`, `is_active`, `is_admin_hidden`, `best_time_to_call`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Faiyaj', 'Mohammad', '', '0959927638,0888227677,0520110007', '', '', '', 'Bagh-110025,BR-0520110007368', '', 'undefined', '', NULL, 0, 'This resume was parsed automatically. You should review it for errors.', '', '', 1, 1, '2018-07-17T16:50:04+05:30', '2018-07-17T16:50:04+05:30', 'faiz_akimam@yahoo.com', '', '', 0, 0, 0, 0, '', '', '', '', 1, 0, ''),
```

The query which i am running is this

```
SELECT candidate_id,date_created, first_name,phone_cell, email1, notes, city, current_pay, desired_pay, key_skills, source, current_employer 
FROM candidate 
WHERE entered_by = '1' AND date_created = '2018-08-23'
```

The problem is this this query is not returning anything. the date_created is in date time format.

Comment: Make sure to delimit your date values in single quotes on your `SELECT`, if not it will be treated as a rest of numbers (2018-08-23 = 1987!). Use `date_created = '2018-08-23'`.

Comment: @EzLo I have done it stilll no working also the field is date time in sql table

Comment: With only the date part in your query tell MySQL that you only want to compare the date portion of the column using `DATE` ... as in `WHERE entered_by = '1' AND DATE(date_created) = '2018-08-23'`

Comment: @Dave It is working

Comment: @Dave Yours is rght answer if you could post it i can accept the same

Comment: @ArunVM Remember that `AND DATE(date_created) = '2018-08-23'` means table fullscan and a corresponding decrease in speed.

Comment: @ArunVM all answers have the same performance because the table does not have an index on `date_created`.Once you add a `date_created` index on that table, the answer from Akina is the best answer.

Comment: _NO!_ ``date_created` varchar(250)` -- Use some proper date type.  Especially if you expect to use it in `WHERE`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From DDL:

```
`date_created` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
```

First question - why? Why not DATETIME?

From query:

```
AND date_created = '2018-08-23'
```

Second question - are you sure there are records containing `'2018-08-23'` value in this field DIRECTLY? without timepart?

---

Recommendations:

- Alter datatype of the field to DATETIME and use proper condition for this datatype.

  ```
  AND date_created BETWEEN '2018-08-23 00:00:00' AND  '2018-08-23 23:59:59'
  ```
- If not, replace the condition with

  ```
  AND date_created LIKE '2018-08-23%'
  ```

Comment: my query is somthing like this SELECT
            candidate_id,date_created,
            first_name,phone_cell,
            email1,
            notes,
            city,
            current_pay,
            desired_pay,
            key_skills,
            source,
            current_employer
       FROM candidate WHERE entered_by = $user_id AND DATE(date_created) = '2018-08-23'";

Comment: @ArunVM I see. It is safe if `candidate` table is compact.

Comment: This is a much more sensible and safer approach, All the table needs is an index.

Comment: If you say `d >= '2018-08-23' AND d < '2018-08-23' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`, then the expression works "correctly" for `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `DATETIME(6)`, `TIMESTAMP`, etc.  But, alas, not for `VARCHAR`!

Answer (score 0):

With only the date part in your query tell MySQL that you only want to compare the date portion of the column using DATE ... as in

```
WHERE entered_by = '1' AND DATE(date_created) = '2018-08-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE entered_by = '1' AND date_created = '2018-08-23'
```

begs for

```
INDEX(entered_by, date_created)
```

I suggest that order for when you change the datatype of `date_created` *away from* `VARCHAR`!

`MYISAM` -- No.  Use InnoDB.  And have a `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: WHERE entered_by = '1' AND date_created = '2018-08-23' this is a condition  in at this example where can i use the same?INDEX(entered_by, date_created)

Comment: ALTER TABLE candidate ADD INDEX(entered_by, date_created);` -- This won't fix the problem of missing rows, but it will improve performance when you get it fixed.

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: @ArunVM - OK is a verbose addon to the other answers.

Comment: i thought this is an answer that is the reason